# How can I find the duration of a song when given its ID using XQuery?

Tags: xquery

First off, yes this is homework - please suggest where I am going wrong,but please **do not do my homework for me**.

I am learning XQuery, and one of my tasks is to take a list of song ID's for a performance and determine the total duration of the performance. Given the snippits below, can anyone point me to where I can determine how to cross reference the songID from the performance to the duration of the song?

I've listed my attempts at the end of the question.

my current XQuery code looks like:

```
   let $songIDs := doc("C:/Users/rob/Downloads/A4_FLOWR.xml")
                     //SongSet/Song 
   for $performance in doc("C:/Users/rob/Downloads/A4_FLOWR.xml")
                       //ContestantSet/Contestant/Performance
      return if($performance/SongRef[. =$songIDs/@SongID])   
      then <performanceDuration>{ 
             data($performance/SongRef)
           }</performanceDuration>
      else ()
```

Which outputs:

```
  <performanceDuration>S005 S003 S004</performanceDuration>
  <performanceDuration>S001 S007 S002</performanceDuration>
  <performanceDuration>S008 S009 S006</performanceDuration>
  <performanceDuration>S002 S004 S007</performanceDuration>
```

Each S00x is the ID of a song, which us found in the referenced xml document (partial document):

```
 <SongSet>
    <Song SongID="S001">
      <Title>Bah Bah Black Sheep</Title>
      <Composer>Mother Goose</Composer>
      <Duration>2.99</Duration>
    </Song>      
    <Song SongID="S005">
      <Title>Thank You Baby</Title>
      <Composer>Shania Twain</Composer>
      <Duration>3.02</Duration>
    </Song>
    </SongSet>
```

The performance section looks like:

```
 <Contestant Name="Fletcher Gee" Hometown="Toronto">
    <Repertoire>
      <SongRef>S001</SongRef>
      <SongRef>S002</SongRef>
      <SongRef>S007</SongRef>
      <SongRef>S010</SongRef>
    </Repertoire>
    <Performance>
      <SongRef>S001</SongRef>
      <SongRef>S007</SongRef>
      <SongRef>S002</SongRef>
    </Performance>
    </Contestant>
```

**My Attempts**

I thought I would use nested loops, but that fails:

```
 let $songs := doc("C:/Users/rob/Downloads/A4_FLOWR.xml")
               //SongSet/Song 
   for $performance in doc("C:/Users/rob/Downloads/A4_FLOWR.xml")
                       //ContestantSet/Contestant/Performance
   return if($performance/SongRef[. =$songs/@SongID])   
     for $song in $songIDs 
          (: gives an error in BaseX about incomplete if :)
   then <performanceDuration>{ 
          data($performance/SongRef)
        }</performanceDuration>
   else ()
```

--Edit--

I've fixed the inner loop, however I am getting all the songs durations, not just the ones that match id's. I have a feeling that this is due to variable scope, but I'm not sure:

```
 let $songs := doc("C:/Users/rob/Downloads/A4_FLOWR.xml")//SongSet/Song 
   for $performance in doc("C:/Users/rob/Downloads/A4_FLOWR.xml")//ContestantSet/Contestant/Performance
   return if($performance/SongRef[. =$songs/@SongID])   

   then <performanceDuration>{  
     for $song in $songs
     return if($performance/SongRef[. =$songs/@SongID]) 
     then      
      sum($song/Duration)
     else ()
  }</performanceDuration>
   else ()

}
```

Output:

```
<performanceDuration>2.99 1.15 3.15 2.2 3.02 2.25 3.45 1.29 2.33 3.1</performanceDuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is syntactic:  you've inserted your inner loop between the condition and the keyword 'then' in a conditional.  Fix that first:

```
return if ($performance/SongRef = $songs/@SongID) then
          <performanceDuration>{
             (: put your inner loop HERE :)
          }</performanceDuration>
else ()
```

Now think yourself into the situation of the query evaluator inside the performanceDuration element.  You have the variable $performance, you can find all the song references using $performance/SongRef, and for each song reference in the performance element, you can find the corresponding song element by matching the SongRef value with $songs/@SongID.

My next step at this point would be to ask myself:

- For a given song reference, how do I find the song element for that song, and then the duration for that song?
- Is there a way to get the sum of some set of durations?  Is there, for example, a `sum()` function?  (I'm pretty sure there is, but at this point I always pull up the Functions and Operators spec and look it up to be sure of the signature.)
- What type does the duration info have?  I'd expect it to be minutes and seconds, and I'd be worrying about duration arithmetic, but your sample makes it look like decimals, which will be easy.